# Invalid first argument Error when fitting Keras model in R Markdown

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, r-markdown

After following keras tutorial on functional API, I'm trying merging 2 Neural Networks, however, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in dim(x) <- length(x) : 
invalid first argument, must be vector (list or atomic)
```

this is the code:

Note:  x_train is a `tibble` and train_gen is `flow_images_from_directory` object.

```
input_img <- layer_input(shape = c(140,140,3) , name = "image")
input_tab <- layer_input(shape = c(ncol(x_train)) , name = "tabular")


cnn <- input_img %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(32, kernel_size = c(3,3) , padding = "same" , 
                activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2,2)) %>% 
  layer_conv_2d(64 , kernel_size = c(3,3) , activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2,2)) %>% 
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dropout(0.5)
  

nn <- input_tab %>% 
  layer_dense(128) %>% 
  layer_activation("relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(64) %>% 
  layer_activation("relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(32) %>% 
  layer_activation("relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(16) %>% 
  layer_activation("relu")

output <- layer_concatenate(c(cnn , nn)) %>% 
  layer_dense(16) %>% 
  layer_activation("relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(6) %>% 
  layer_activation("sigmoid")

model <- keras_model(inputs = c(input_img  ,  input_tab) ,
                     outputs = output) %>% 
  compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy" , optimizer = optimizer_adam() ,
          metrics = "accuracy")

callbacks <- callback_early_stopping(monitor = "val_loss" , patience = 5)

final_history <- model %>% fit(
  x = list(train_gen , x_train),
  y = list(train_gen$classes , x_train),
  epochs = 50 ,
  callbacks = callbacks,
  validation_split = 0.2)

Error in dim(x) <- length(x) : 
invalid first argument, must be vector (list or atomic)
```

After long searching online i could not find any help on this.

**why this error is produced?**

Comment: Would you provide link to this tutorial?

Comment: sure , i followed 2 of them: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/09/whose-dream-is-this-when-and-how-to-use-the-keras-functional-api/  https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?